# A feature in EasyMock that is not there in Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, easymock

Is there any good feature in EasyMock that is not there or not properly handled (as compared to EasyMock) in Mockito?

I would like to know about some feature like for eg. Mockito supports easy injection of all mocks into the Class Under Test by using the `@ InjectMocks`, which is not the case in EasyMock (out of the box).  Similarly are there any features in EasyMock which are either not there or not handled as good as in EasyMock?

Comment: Object spied = spy(xxx);
when(spied.yyy()).thenReturn(xxx); 
this may throw exception, and you have to use doReturn(xxx);
that is something not some nice in mockito i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One feature that comes to mind is the support for implicitly verified expectations, which Mockito lacks:

```
@Test
public void usingEasyMock()
{
    Collaborator mock = createMock(Collaborator.class);

    expect(mock.registerXyz("xyz")).andReturn(true);
    replay(mock);

    new ClassUnderTest().doSomething(mock);

    verify(mock);
}


@Test
public void usingMockito()
{
    Collaborator mock = mock(Collaborator.class);

    when(mock.registerXyz("xyz")).thenReturn(true);

    new ClassUnderTest().doSomething(mock);

    verify(mock).registerXyz("xyz");
}
```

Note the duplicate invocation to `registerXyz("xyz")` in the second test. Mockito could perhaps add a `times(n)` method to be used together with calls to `thenReturn(...)` (which EasyMock has). This would avoid having to duplicate code in situations like this.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  This feature was explicitly added in Mockito though it is ofcourse not so convenient.  Yes, it makes a point :-)  Thanks for sharing it.